# How can i improve arrowhead line drawing using CoreGraphics?

Tags: objective-c, core-graphics

In my app i have view where user can draw arrows. 
It works almost perfect.
If i swipe slowly i have nice result.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fr3Uz.png)

Bu if i try to swipe faster i got the arrowhead somewhere but not at the very end of line.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHcRT.png)

Sorry, due to my reputation i can't post images here.

How Can i improve arrowhead line drawing to draw however fast i swipe?

To do this i use next method -

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

mouseSwiped = YES;



UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
   [self.tempDrawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

  CGContextClearRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height));

   double slopy, cosy, siny;
   // Arrow size
   double length = 10.0;
   double width = 10.0;

   slopy = atan2((firstPoint.y - lastMovePoint.y), (firstPoint.x - lastMovePoint.x));
   cosy = cos(slopy);
   siny = sin(slopy);


   CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), firstPoint.x, firstPoint.y);
   CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
        //here is the tough part - actually drawing the arrows
   //a total of 6 lines drawn to make the arrow shape

   CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastMovePoint.x, lastMovePoint.y);

   CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),
                           lastMovePoint.x +  (length * cosy - ( width / 2.0 * siny )),
                           lastMovePoint.y +  (length * siny + ( width / 2.0 * cosy )) );
   CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),
                           lastMovePoint.x +  (length * cosy + width / 2.0 * siny),
                           lastMovePoint.y -  (width / 2.0 * cosy - length * siny) );
   CGContextClosePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());

   CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
   CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), brush );
   CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), red, green, blue, 1.0);
   CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),kCGBlendModeNormal);

   CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
   self.tempDrawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   [self.tempDrawImage setAlpha:opacity];
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

   lastMovePoint = currentPoint;
```

Comment: You might think about moving the path construction into its own function to simplify your code.  You can use [this category on `UIBezierPath`](https://gist.github.com/4146780), which is explained [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13559449/77567).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience when drawing with core graphics, when swiping fast over a view, the distance between the points every time `touchesMoved:` gets called is larger, and I see that you are using a `lastMovePoint` which can be further than you'd like, giving you unwanted results. This does not happen when moving slowly and the distance between each point is minimal (sometimes even less than 1 point)

I suggest working only with the `firstPoint` and `currentPoint`, calculate the angle and draw the arrow using only that, because, when it comes to it, to draw a line you only need the first and last point, it doesn't matter where the user touched before :)