# Curved arrow from one point to another

Tags: ios, swift

I need to draw a curved arrow from one point to another. I did manage to get an straight arrow from below extension.

```
extension UIBezierPath {

static func arrow(from start: CGPoint, to end: CGPoint, tailWidth: CGFloat, headWidth: CGFloat, headLength: CGFloat) -> UIBezierPath {
    let length = hypot(end.x - start.x, end.y - start.y)
    let tailLength = length - headLength

    func p(_ x: CGFloat, _ y: CGFloat) -> CGPoint { return CGPoint(x: x, y: y) }
    let points: [CGPoint] = [
        p(0, tailWidth / 2),
        p(tailLength, tailWidth / 2),
        p(tailLength, headWidth / 2),
        p(length, 0),
        p(tailLength, -headWidth / 2),
        p(tailLength, -tailWidth / 2),
        p(0, -tailWidth / 2)
    ]

    let cosine = (end.x - start.x) / length
    let sine = (end.y - start.y) / length
    let transform = CGAffineTransform(a: cosine, b: sine, c: -sine, d: cosine, tx: start.x, ty: start.y)

    let path = CGMutablePath()
    path.addLines(between: points, transform: transform)


    path.closeSubpath()

    return self.init(cgPath: path)
}}
```

What I'm currently getting from above code.
[image: What I have now]

What I need.

[image: What I need]

Comment: “Curved” is not very specific. How do you want it to curve? Maybe you could post an image showing what you want.

Comment: @robmayoff will edit my answer

Comment: try with my 2nd answer, just change radius as per your convenience. let me know if there is issue

Comment: @MShah couldn't get it working. I need an arrow with a curved line. But it doesn't draw an curved line

Comment: The code you posted was copied from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37985645/77567). I explained the code in detail in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13559449/77567). Did you read the explanation? You can use the technique I described there to develop code that draws a curved arrow.

Answer (score 2):

Use ***addArc*** method for creating curve line(instead of straight line):-

```
path.addArc(tangent1End: start, tangent2End: end, radius: 30)
```

or

```
path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100), radius: 30, startAngle: 270, endAngle: 360, clockwise: true, transform: transform)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created a curved arrow and used a quadratic bezier path as described here: [Core Graphics, Part 4: A Path! A Path!](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/core-graphics-part-4-a-path-a-path/)

[image: Quad Curve Animation]

```
path.move(to: firstPoint)
path.addQuadCurve(to: endPoint, control: controlPoint)
```

I then created the arrow head by finding the angle between the control and end points:

```
controlPoint.angle(to: endPoint)
```

Then I found the points to draw the arrow head lines by adding and subtracting from this angle and adding a distance from the end point:

```
func offset(from point: CGPoint, distance: CGFloat, degrees: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
    let radians = degrees * .pi / 180
    let vertical = sin(radians) * distance
    let horizontal = cos(radians) * distance
    return point.applying(CGAffineTransform(translationX: horizontal, y: vertical))
}
```

Finally I just draw lines to these two points.